# Section floor view - Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to be able to filter my uploaded Revit buildings to display certain floors (e.g. basement, first floor, roof). I am aware that I can section the view from the toolbar but I want to section the view by tapping buttons (in my case, tree buttons: Basement - Floor - Roof).

I have been looking at this tutorial:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-application/

But here I'd need to upload pre-sectioned models of all the tree views. Is there any other way, or would I go with the option from the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the section planes from the API, so you could create buttons that invoke the API and control how section planes are being set. Take a look at `setCutPlanes` method in the [viewer API documentation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/).

Here is an article that illustrates how to use this method: [Viewer setCutPlanes](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-setcutplanes)

You can also take a look at this blog post that expose how I used [ThreeCSG](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG) ([Constructive solid geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry)) to perform boolean operations in the viewer and isolate walls specific to each floor: [Boolean Operations in the Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/boolean-operations-forge-viewer).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Philippe.